# Oracle FOR XML AUTO

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle11g

The last time I used Oracle was when 8i was just coming out so I have pretty much forgotten everything I may have know about Oracle, much less what is still relevant.  In all these years I have been using MS SQL Server.  I want to quickly serialize a result set in to XML.  Where might I discover if there is an equivalent Oracle 11g construct as the SQL Server FOR XML AUTO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a quick way is [DBMS_XMLGEN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_xmlgen.htm).

```
SQL> select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from emp where rownum <= 2') xmlstr from dual;

XMLSTR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <EMPNO>7369</EMPNO>
  <ENAME>SMITH</ENAME>
  <JOB>CLERK</JOB>
  <MGR>7902</MGR>
  <HIREDATE>17-DEC-80</HIREDATE>
  <SAL>800</SAL>
  <DEPTNO>20</DEPTNO>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <EMPNO>7499</EMPNO>
  <ENAME>ALLEN</ENAME>
  <JOB>SALESMAN</JOB>
  <MGR>7698</MGR>
  <HIREDATE>20-FEB-81</HIREDATE>
  <SAL>1600</SAL>
  <COMM>300</COMM>
  <DEPTNO>30</DEPTNO>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: If it cuts off before the end, try this first: set pages 0; set linesize 150; set long 9999999; set head off;